# Azure DevOps Pipeline multi job dependency

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

consider the following code:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: ra
    displayName: Run Job A
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: rb
    displayName: Run Job B
    type: boolean
    default: true

jobs:
  - job: A
    condition: and(succeeded(), ${{ eq(parameters.ra, 'true') }})
    steps:
      - script: echo "A"
  
  - job: B
    condition: and(succeeded(), ${{ eq(parameters.rb, 'true') }})
    steps:
      - script: echo "B"
  
  - job: C
    dependsOn:
      - A
      - B
    condition: |
        and(succeeded(),
            or(
                in(dependencies.A.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped'),
                in(dependencies.B.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped')
            )
        )
    steps:
      - script: echo "C"
```

What i try to do:
jobs A and B should run or not based on parameters, job c only when either A or B, or both have finished successfully.

Problem:
this does not work as is because of `and(succeeded() ...` part of the condition. If i remove it, than it works **BUT** job C can no longer be canceled, because cancel event is invoked through `succeeded()`.

Is there a way to achieve this without loosing the cancellation capabilities?

Comment: How do you want to cancel job c?

Comment: Would  `not(canceled())` help you?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions

Comment: @Krzysztof Madej
Running Azure DevOps pipelines have a "Cancel" button in the upper right corner within a run. If you have "Stages", than those have a separate "Cancel" button as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would not(canceled()) help you?
> learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/…

As @marvin_x said, `not(canceled())` was indeed the sought solution.
The code now works and looks as follows:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: ra
    displayName: Run Job A
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: rb
    displayName: Run Job B
    type: boolean
    default: true

jobs:
  - job: A
    condition: and(succeeded(), ${{ eq(parameters.ra, 'true') }})
    steps:
      - script: echo "A"
  
  - job: B
    condition: and(succeeded(), ${{ eq(parameters.rb, 'true') }})
    steps:
      - script: echo "B"
  
  - job: C
    dependsOn:
      - A
      - B
    condition: |
        and(
            not(
                canceled()
            ),
            in(dependencies.A.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped'),
            in(dependencies.B.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped')
        )
    steps:
      - script: echo "C"
```

You can also add an additional, separate parameter condition to job C, as in A or B, which would also be placed in `condition:`, within the `and(...)` function.

Alternative way that should work (not tested due to lack of time) would be to introduce stages. Something like:

- Jobs A and B run in stage S1
- Job C runs in stage S2
- Stage S2 is dependent on stage S1